# How can I subtract timestamp results from `date` in one line of shell?

Tags: bash, shell, math, command-line

I can generate two timestamps like so:

```
date +"%s" -d "$(curl -s --head http://google.com | grep ^Date: | sed 's/Date: //g')"
// Result: 1417800327

date +"%s"
// Result: 1417800325
```

How can I subtract them with only one line?

```
echo "$((1417800327-1417800325))"
// Result: 2
```

But I want something closer to:

```
echo "$(( (date +"%s" -d "$(curl -s --head http://google.com | grep ^Date: | sed 's/Date: //g')") - (date +"%s")))"
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Can I see the whole command?

Comment: That's literally the transformation you need. Compare `echo "(date)"` to `echo "$(date)"` then make the same change in your arithmetic context in that line.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you actually run that or put that on the command line. That was simply indicative of the *exact* change you needed to make. Mentally apply that change to your command and it will work. See @sputnick's answer for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
LANG=C echo $(( $(date +%s) - $(date -d "$(curl -s --head http://google.com 2>&1 | awk -F'Date: ' '/^Date:/{print $2}')" +%s) ))
```

or splitted multi-lines for readability :

```
LANG=C echo $((
    $(date +%s) - $(
        date -d "$(curl -s --head http://google.com |
            awk -F'Date: ' '/^Date:/{print $2}'
    )" +%s)
))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

  ##On Linux. start time, do something, find end time.
  st=`date +%s`; sleep 10; et=`date +%s`;
  ##On SunOS instead of using date command, use `truss /usr/bin/date 2>&1 | grep ^time | awk -F"= " '{print $2}'`;

  ##substract to find elapsed time
  elt=$((et-st)); 

  ##find elapsed hours, minutes, seconds
  eh=$((elt/3600)); em=$(($((elt%3600))/60)); es=$(($((elt%3600))%60));
  elt=`printf "%02d:%02d:%02d%s" $((eh)) $((em)) $((es))`;

  ##show elapsed time in user friendly way
  echo - Elapsed time: $elt
```

**Output**:

```
- Elapsed time: 00:00:10
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a subshell function  with one big command bash line

```
(timestamp=`date +"%s" -d "$(curl -s --head http://google.com | grep ^Date: | sed 's/Date: //g')"`;date=`date +"%s"`;let "time_difference= $timestamp-$date";echo "$time_difference"; )
```